# webpack-modernizr-loader loader with Vue CLI 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, modernizr, vue-cli

I am in the middle of transferring a project from an older version of Webpack and Vue.js to Vue cli 3, which is working well, except I am having trouble figuring out how to get an additional loader to work. The loader is 'webpack-modernizr-loader', which loads modernizr and allows me to check if a user's browser can do promises and other modern JavaScript features.

My old `webpack.config.js` looks something like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
     ...
      {
        loader: 'webpack-modernizr-loader',
        options: {
          options: [
          ],
          'feature-detects': [
            'test/es6/promises',
            'test/audio/webaudio',
            'test/websockets'
          ]
        },
        test: /empty-alias-file\.js$/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, './empty-alias-file.js')
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

With Vue cli 3 I have a `vue.congfig.js` file, and am unsure how to get the above translated into it. So far my most recent attempt looks like this:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  ... 
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          loader: 'webpack-modernizr-loader',
          options: {
            options: [
            ],
            'feature-detects': [
              'test/es6/promises',
              'test/audio/webaudio',
              'test/websockets'
            ]
          },
          test: /empty-alias-file\.js$/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, './empty-alias-file.js')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that is not working. I would love a point in the right direction or an example of existing code that does something similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few hours of trying to fix this myself I ended up with this:

1. Make sure your config is named `.modernizrrc` (without .js), otherwise you will get all kinds of errors.
   *If I had to guess; this is probably related to it being included by babel incorrectly, and could be evaded by excluding the file somehow).*
2. Make sure you have **webpack-modernizr-loader** and **modernizr** installed.

## main.js

```
import modernizr from 'modernizr'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

I actually don't use modernizr in the JS code yet, but I had to include it to get the classes to render into the HTML element. That is why it is unused (and the line is disabled in eslint).

## vue.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version;

module.exports = {
  baseUrl: '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
      alias: {
        '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        '@': path.resolve('src/'),
        modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, '.modernizrrc'),
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => ({
        ...options,
        compilerOptions: {
          ...options.compilerOptions,
          preserveWhitespace: true,
        },
      }));
    config.module
      .rule('modernizr')
      .test(/\.modernizrrc$/)
      .use('webpack-modernizr-loader')
      .loader('webpack-modernizr-loader');
  },
};
```

## .modernizrrc

(The arrays are shortened for the sake of this answers length)

```
module.exports = {
    "minify": true,
    "options": [
      "mq",
      ...
      "prefixed",
    ],
    "feature-detects": [
      "test/css/all",
      ...
      "test/css/animations",
    ]
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get any joy at all with this - The build would just fail because it couldn't read the config file. After 3 hours I gave up and wrote my own detection code. Annoying as I'd like to have been able to use other elements of Modernizr later on.